# Use the same formula and the same range but on a different tab in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, tabs

I have 12 types of apartments. Each has 7 systems, which are made up of a labour element and a material element. I want to summarise this information on a summary page that looks like this:

Apartment 1
System 1
System 2
System 3
System 4
System 5
System 6
System 7

Apartment 2
...
...

For example cell B9 will have a formula "=SUM(Apartment1!O$34:O$39)" to sum the subcomponents of System 1 in Apartment 1.

What I want to do is to copy this formula and paste it across the other apartment types to sum up their total values for System 1 - so the formula has to refer to the next tab eg "=SUM(Apartment2!O$34:O$39)".

Is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

if you take apartment number from cell range ex("A1"). you can use the below formula

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Apartment"&A1&"!O$34:O$39"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write same formula at a particular cell in all sheets of workbook then do the following:

[image]

**1.** Right click on the first worksheet and click on `Select All Sheets`
**2.** Then select any cell (in your case select `Cell B9`) in `Sheet1` and write your formula as `=SUM(O$34:O$39)`

**3.** Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now check all the sheets. Cell B9 of all sheets should have formula `=SUM(O$34:O$39)`
**______________________________________________________________________________**

You can also do this using VBA as:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Range("B9").Formula = "=SUM(" & ws.Name & "!O$34:O$39)"
    Next
End Sub
```